# Unable to delete data, MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have a large database containing around 40 million rows in 5 tables. I need to delete rows from one table for which a column has values that don't exist in the second table.

I have tried writing queries to delete some rows as well as insert the rows that I don't want to delete into another table:

`DELETE FROM user_followersid WHERE followersIds_generatedId IN (SELECT * FROM generatedfollowers)`

`CREATE TABLE tempfollowersids as SELECT * FROM user_followersid WHERE followersIds_generatedId IN (SELECT generatedId from followersid WHERE followerId IN (SELECT * FROM topusers));`

It takes a lot of time for the deletions and fails every time at the end and reports the following error:

`ERROR 1206 (HY000): The total number of locks exceeds the lock table size`

I have even tried deleting only few rows at a time using `LIMIT` but it is also taking lot of time. I know that `IN` is extremely slow. But I can't find any alternative way of writing my queries.

Any ideas on how should I delete the rows?

Comment: You need to any delete records in smaller batches (i.e. try limiting the number of records you delete in one go by adding additional filters to your where clause) or you need to change the mysql config. See http://rackerhacker.com/2010/02/16/mysql-the-total-number-of-locks-exceeds-the-lock-table-size-2/ for advice.

Comment: Do you have an index on `user_followersid.followersIds_generatedId` ?

Answer (score 4):

You say:

> which a column has values that **don't** exist in the second table

So, shouldn't your query be:

```
DELETE FROM user_followersid 
WHERE followersIds_generatedId NOT IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM generatedfollowers)
```

Comment: Good point. In fact, before deleting rows based on a select it is always a good idea to perform the select in isolation and check the resulting rows.

Comment: I already did that. `generatedfollowers` contains the ids of the rows that I want to delete. So the query that I wrote is correct. Sorry that the question is a bit misleading.

Answer (score 0):

Your `IN` statement:

```
DELETE FROM user_followersid 
WHERE followersIds_generatedId IN 
      ( SELECT generatedId
        FROM generatedfollowers 
      )
```

can can also be written with `EXISTS`, as:

```
DELETE FROM user_followersid AS uf
WHERE EXISTS 
      ( SELECT * 
        FROM generatedfollowers AS gf 
        WHERE gf.generatedId = uf.followersIds_generatedId
      )
```

and with `JOIN`, as:

```
DELETE uf 
FROM user_followersid AS uf
  JOIN generatedfollowers AS gf 
    ON gf.generatedId = uf.followersIds_generatedId
```

You cannot use `LIMIT x` with the third (join) statement.